# MS Access: Empty all tables in DB

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-delete

Is there a possibility to empty every table of my DB? Obviously there is one way to use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Table1", dbFailOnError
```

for every table.

But then I have to use this code for every table. It would be nice if there was a solution with `Loop` or something which is not related to the tables names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop thru all local tables using code

```
Dim tdf As TableDef

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [" & tdf.Name & "]", dbFailOnError 
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, but I got one problem. Some table names include "-" for example "tblProducts-A" (I know this titling is stupid -.-). This results in a syntax error. How can I solve this??

Comment: I thought CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * FROM  [ " & tdf.Name], dbFailOnError  would help. But it doesn't...

Comment: Yes, you right, forgot about brackets. Edited the answer.